# MathGL and FLTK cmake on Mac OS X: Not finding symbols

Tags: macos, cmake, fltk, mathgl

I'm having trouble getting cmake to find and link the necessary libraries for MathGL and FLTK.

```
Linking CXX executable filter.app/Contents/MacOS/filter
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mgl_create_graph_fltk", referenced from:
      _main in filter.cpp.o
  "_mgl_fltk_thr", referenced from:
      _main in filter.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using the default FLTK finder cmake script, which comes with brewed CMake 3.0.2 on OS X.

Here are the relevant portions of my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(MathGL 2.2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MATHGL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(FLTK REQUIRED)
include_directories(${FLTK_INCLUDE_DIR})
#link_directories(${FLTK_LIBRARIES}) # tried it with and without this line

add_executable(filter ${BUNDLE_MODE} src/filter.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
  filter
  ${MATHGL2_LIBRARIES}
  ${FLTK_LIBRARIES}
  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
)
```

If I uncomment the `link_directories` line, I get an additional error:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:73 (link_directories):
  This command specifies the relative path

    -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework ApplicationServices -lz

  as a link directory.

  Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the
  source dir.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
```

It seems like it's trying to do `-L-framework Carbon`, etc., when these are already being linked via the `BUNDLE_MODE` var in `add_executable`. I suspect this particular `FindFLTK2.cmake` was not properly tested on OS X, and am not quite sure how to fix it.

Can anyone suggest a simple fix?

Comment: Not familiar with cmake, but it looks like the trouble is linking to mathGL. Have you checked, manually, that the mathGL libs are where you think they are? As a brute force check, have you tried compiling from the command line with g++ and `fltk-config` and linking to MathGL from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It seems that the instructions in both `FindMathGL.cmake` and `FindMathGL2.cmake` were incorrect. Here is the corrected cmake instruction set. This also works for Qt, not just FLTK.

```
find_package(MathGL2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS FLTK) # or Qt instead of FLTK
include_directories(${MATHGL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(filter ${BUNDLE_MODE} src/filter.cpp) # leave out BUNDLE_MODE if not on Darwin

target_link_libraries(
  filter
  ${MATHGL2_LIBRARIES}
  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Much easier.